# Access denied for GCP bucket shared with other gmail users

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I'm struggling to give third parties access to a GCP bucket which they can access at `https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucketname>/`. I've been following the steps set out for [GCP Authenticated browser downloads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration#browser).

The bucket has uniform access level and has public access set to off. This bucket and associated project is not within an organisation -- this is run off a private account.

I've used the console to add two users with `Storage Object Viewer` permissions to the bucket. However if I log in (using a different browser) as one of these users I get an Access Denied message.

I wondered if the permission error is due to only adding the users after using `gsutil` to upload content, so I tried to add read permissions on the bucket:

```
gsutil acl ch -r -u <gmailuser>:R gs://<bucketname>/
CommandException: Failed to set acl for gs://<bucketname>/subdir/. Please ensure you have OWNER-role access to this resource.
```

Since I'm running `gsutil` as the project and bucket owner perhaps I've messed up permissions somehow. Insights gratefully received.

---

Update 27 October

**Need an organisation?**

Based on @Hemanth's hepful comments and further testing this problem appears to be an issue with my needing an organisation, something not set out in the docs. I don't want to setup an organisation with allied adoption of one of my domains and necessity of migrating projects.

I don't know if Google are trying to migrate individuals to forcibly setting up organisations, but if so the errors reported need to be improved as do the docs. Apart from ruining a sales pipeline of gmail users adopting cloud storage, this issue may also account for buckets being opened publicly as people try to understand this problem.

[Dear Google. Why is this so hard?](https://steve-yegge.medium.com/dear-google-cloud-your-deprecation-policy-is-killing-you-ee7525dc05dc)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [predefined ACLS guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#predefined-acl), by applying a predefined ACL to an existing bucket or object, you completely replace the existing bucket or object ACL with the predefined ACL. This change might cause you to lose access to the bucket or object ACL in some cases. This might remove the Bucket owner permissions and when trying to access it is asking the owner permissions.

You can use the [IAM role storage.objectAdmin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#acls) so that you have the permission necessary to update the object's ACL and correct the change.  Grant the `Storage Legacy Bucket Owner` in IAM and also  try giving "Storage Admin" and "Storage Object Admin/Creator/Viewer"  permissions  which gives owner roles to the bucket.

You can also grant the owner permission by using the below command :

```
gsutil acl ch -p owners-example-project:W gs://example-bucket
```

Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl#ch-examples) for more examples.

Updated answer :

- Seems to be you might be using the [free tier account](https://cloud.google.com/free/) which might run
  out of free limits. So, can you try by upgrading your account to a
  paid one which will have a billing account also.
- This error may also occur because the Cloud Storage bucket you are
  trying to use does not exist.  You may verify this by clicking the
  blue button titled [Open the Cloud Storage Browser](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets)
- For billing account assistance, open a Billing Support Request using the Billing Support Requests form provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/#contact_support).

Comment: Hi @Hemanth, thanks for your helpful note. I continue to have trouble using gsutil to add acls after adding the IAM roles you mentioned. I made a new bucket with default Object and Bucket permissions and it has the same problem. Do you think this might be because of the lack of an organisation? Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I've found more info. GCP is throwing errors on bucket tests reporting "The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account". This is wrong, but seems to be due to the fact I don't have an organisation associated with this account. Getting Google support help also requires an organisation, a sort of doom loop for this problem.

Comment: Hi @Hemanth. Thanks for the further info to your answer.
1. no, this isn't a free tier account.
2. I've verified the bucket exists with `gsutil ls`
3. Billing Support requests require an organisation!
I suspect the problem is that I have no organisation but there is no way of verifying it.

Comment: @rorycl : if you create a billing account then it automatically creates the organisation. Any projects you created previously will be listed under "No organization", and this is normal. The organization resource will appear and the new project you created will be linked to it automatically. You will need to move any projects you created under "No organization" into your new organization resource. For instructions on how to move your projects, see [Migrating projects into an organization resource](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration).

Comment: As you stated there is No organisation, Kindly create a billing account and if you need further assistance reach out to Billing support with this might your issue get resolved.  Refer to this [Cloud doc](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization) for more information.

Comment: Hi @Hemanth. Thanks for your further notes. I don't want to make an organisation. To do that I have to let Google adopt a domain of mine, I believe. I have no wish to do that and to migrate my projects to the organisation. I simply wish to give controlled access to a bucket using the commands provided by Cloud console or `gsutil` or `gcloud` as set out in the docs. I think I've hit a serious bug in GCP Storage which may account for the many buckets that are publicly accessible but should not be.

Comment: @rorycl: if you feel it is a bug raise an issue in a [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).